# Slide upping in jquery with ids

Tags: jquery

```
var Ids = $('.head:has(:checkbox:checked)')
               .map(function() { return this.id })
               .get(); alert(Ids);
```

i have ids with above code.However,
i cannot slide up with these Ids with

Why this does not work ?

```
function(response){
        alert("Başarıyla silindi");
         $('#'+Ids).each('slow', function() {
    }).slideUp();
```

Comment: What does `Ids` contain? An array of strings?

Comment: ID's must be unique, and `$('#'+Ids)` is not really valid, your trying to add a hash to an array, which will give you nothing, remove the hashsign to iterate over the ID's, and read the documentation on how to structure your each() function.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.each(Ids, function() {
   $('#'+this).slideUp('slow');
});
```

This would do pretty much the same:

```
var Ids = $('.head:checked');

$.each(Ids, function() {
   $('#'+this.id).slideUp('slow');
});​
```

or just:

```
$('.head:checked').slideUp('slow');
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `Ids` is an array, so you cannot directly use `$("#"+Ids)`.

Next, even if Ids was not an array and referrred to a string variable `$("#"+Ids)` would return an `HTML element`, which does not have `.each()` function.

The correct way to do this is

```
$.each(Ids, function(v) {
  $("#"+v).slideUp("slow"):
});
```

Comment: @MertMetin, Sorry, typo. fixed it

Comment: @adeneo, That was a typo, I fixed it sorry.